# Three.js r73 - rotating multiple objects back and forth as a unique object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a simulation of a box that unfolds each different face, each face is a different geometry with pivots on the bottom of the geometry.

When i MouseDown on a face, it's supposed to tween rotate in its x axis 90degrees. And on MouseDown again the opposite value as if the box face was closed.

The problem happens that the values rendered on the tween are not uniform.

Below is the MouseDown function:

```
    function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        controls.enabled = false;
        if (SELECTED) {     
            if (SELECTED == intersects[ 0 ].object) {
                //same selected;
                new TWEEN.Tween(rotationTween).to( targetB, 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                SELECTED.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotationTween.x );
                }).start();
                //TWEEN.remove(Tween);
            } else {
                //new selected; 

                SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;  

                new TWEEN.Tween(rotationTween).to( target, 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                SELECTED.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotationTween.x );
                }).start();
                //TWEEN.remove(Tween);              
            }
        } else {
            //first time selected;
            SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            new TWEEN.Tween( rotationTween ).to(target , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
            SELECTED.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), rotationTween.x );
            }).start();
            //TWEEN.remove(Tween);
        }
    }

}
```

Any other details give me a msg. Thx.

Comment: Not an answer, but do not instantiate a new `THREE.Vector3(1,0,0)` every update. Create one and reuse it.

Comment: are they uniform if you change the `TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut` to `TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None` ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to be brief but I have to explain my situation:

The OBJECTIVE: to create a cube with individual faces that opens individually on each click. 
Furthermore I got to a point where only one face is opened on click. If other opened it should close. It was a bit far from my project since when the face is "clicked" the hole scene would stay freeze, no listeners. The faces also have the same root hierarchy in the code above, wich feels wrong if you thinck in a box, where the top and bottom face would be children of the back face (in my project case).

I got really stuck when I had to rotate the faces over tweens. First problem was after the initial faces positioning THEY WILL KEEP THEY'RE ROTATION VALUES. So the left face of the box will start the render with a rotation.y = Math.PI/2, and so on. Here follows the cube creation code:

interactFace.js

```
interactFace = function (fText, fSize, matColor) {
    //create face mesh
    this.mat = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: matColor, opacity: 0.3, transparent: true, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
    this.geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(fSize,fSize);
    this.geometry = new THREE.Geometry();   
    this.geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3( fSize/2,  0, 0 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( -fSize/2,  0, 0 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( fSize/2,  fSize, 0 ),
        new THREE.Vector3( -fSize/2, fSize, 0 )
    );
    this.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
    this.geometry.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 1, 2, 3 ) );

    this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.mat);

    this.textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( fText, {
        size: fSize/8,
        height: 0,
        curveSegments: 4,
        font: "verdana",
        weight: "normal",
        style: "normal",
        bevelThickness: 0,
        bevelSize: 0,
        bevelEnabled: false });
    this.TextMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( [
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x000000, shading: THREE.FlatShading } ), // front
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x000000, shading: THREE.SmoothShading } ) // side
    ] );
    this.textMesh = new THREE.Mesh( this.textGeo, this.TextMaterial);
    this.build(fSize);
};
interactFace.prototype = {
    constructor: interactFace,
    build: function (fSize) {   
        this.mesh.castShadow = true;    

        this.textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
        this.textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
        //this.geometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( 0, 0, -fSize/2 ) );
        //this.textGeo.position.set(  -fSize/4, fSize/2, 0.01 );
        this.textGeo.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( -fSize/4, fSize/2, 0.01 ) );

        this.mesh.add(this.textMesh);

    }
};
```

and then the cube assembled with the faces. I left commented the options i tried after desperate moments. I had an early problem using rotation on objects and after accessing then by they're parents they rotate by the parents axis, giving me problems. So I switched rotation to  rotateOnAxis, witch worked for this problem, but with the rotation.order switched for the top axis of the faces, this option became useless, hence no need for additional vector creation for this case:

interactCube.js

```
interactCube = function (fSize, objects) {
    this.pivot = new THREE.Group();
    var menuItems = [ 'PG 01', 'PG 02', 'PG 03', 'PG 04', 'PG 05', 'PG 06' ];
    var menuItemsCoordinates = [
        [ 0, 0 , 0, 0, -Math.PI/2, -Math.PI/2], // rotation.x
        [ 0, Math.PI/2 , Math.PI, -Math.PI/2, Math.PI, Math.PI], // rotation.y
        [ 0, 0 , 0, 0, Math.PI, 0], // rotation.z

        [ 0, fSize/2 , 0, -fSize/2, 0, 0], //position.x
        [ 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, fSize], //position.y
        [ fSize, fSize/2 , 0, fSize/2, 0, 0] //position.z   <-- last item is top face, child of front face

    ];      
    this.build(fSize, menuItems, menuItemsCoordinates); 
}
interactCube.prototype = {
    constructor: interactCube,
    build: function (fSize, menuItems, menuItemsCoordinates) {  
        for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {        

            this.face = new interactFace(menuItems[i], fSize, 0x585858);
            this.face.mesh.rotation.order = 'ZYX';      
    //<-- ROTATION BEFORE TRANSLATION
/*
            this.face.mesh.rotation.set( menuItemsCoordinates[0][i], menuItemsCoordinates[1][i], menuItemsCoordinates[2][i]);
            this.face.mesh.position.set( menuItemsCoordinates[3][i], menuItemsCoordinates[4][i], menuItemsCoordinates[5][i] );
*/  

            var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( menuItemsCoordinates[0][i] );
            this.face.mesh.applyMatrix(rotation);
            var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY( menuItemsCoordinates[1][i] );
            this.face.mesh.applyMatrix(rotation);
            var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ( menuItemsCoordinates[2][i] );
            this.face.mesh.applyMatrix(rotation);   

            var translation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(menuItemsCoordinates[3][i], menuItemsCoordinates[4][i], menuItemsCoordinates[5][i]);
            this.face.mesh.applyMatrix(translation);        

            /*
            this.face.mesh.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), menuItemsCoordinates[0][i] );
            this.face.mesh.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), menuItemsCoordinates[1][i] );
            this.face.mesh.rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), menuItemsCoordinates[2][i] );
            this.face.mesh.translateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0), menuItemsCoordinates[3][i] );
            this.face.mesh.translateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), menuItemsCoordinates[4][i] );
            this.face.mesh.translateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,0,1), menuItemsCoordinates[5][i] );
            */
            /*
            if( ( (i + 1) < menuItems.length  ) ) {             
                this.pivot.add(this.face.mesh);
                objects.push(this.face.mesh);
            } else {                
                this.pivot.children[ i - 1 ].add(this.face.mesh);
                objects.push(this.face.mesh);
            }
            */
            this.pivot.add(this.face.mesh);
                objects.push(this.face.mesh);

        }
    }


}
```

Then I got to the template, the previous code of this problem, I was having issues on creating a unique value for the tween to work with all the faces. All side faces worked very well since they had they rotation.x value to 0. The top and bottom faces was giving me issues since they initial rotation.x values different from 0.
I started then to switch the tween functions to an increment of the initial value. WRONG. incrementing angle inside tween functions is a nightmare,
So I started to research about sin and cos. I got some time a go a job of a 3d menu in flash, whereas i had to map dynamic buttons in a circular position. And I remembered something about the radian values on code languages didn't work exactly as we calculate in degrees. And that I had to give fixed values to the rotation angles. Almost like incrementing and decrementing but without the errors given in the tweens.

So I managed to resolve that by creating 2 vars, one that gets the initial values of the rotation.x of the selected object, and another is this first value incremented by Math.PI/2. So on the  onUpdate function I could define a dynamic fixed value, provided by a incremented argument outside the function.

template.js

```
var container, stats;
var controls;
var camera, scene, renderer;
var cubeMenu;
var objects = [];
var raycaster;
var mouse, INTERSECTED, SELECTED;
var opened = false;

function renderTemplate() {
    init();
    animate();  
}
function init() {
    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
    camera.position.z = 100;
    camera.position.y = 20;

    controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );
    controls.rotateSpeed = 1.0;
    controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
    controls.noZoom = false;
    controls.noPan = false;
    controls.staticMoving = true;
    controls.dynamicDampingFactor = 0.3;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    createScenario(scene);

    cubeMenu = new interactCube(18, objects);                   
    scene.add( cubeMenu.pivot );        

    raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
    mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    renderer.sortObjects = false;
    renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
    renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFShadowMap;

    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var info = document.createElement( 'div' );
    info.style.position = 'absolute';
    info.style.top = '10px';
    info.style.width = '100%';
    info.style.textAlign = 'center';
    info.innerHTML = 'interactive faced cube menu';
    container.appendChild( info );
    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
    //
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false );
    window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );
}
function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
}
function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;     
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );           
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );          
            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.emissive.getHex();
            INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( 0x22aa22 );               
        }
        container.style.cursor = 'pointer';         
    } else {
        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.emissive.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
        INTERSECTED = null;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';            
    }
}
function onDocumentTouchStart( event ) {                
    event.preventDefault();             
    event.clientX = event.touches[0].clientX;
    event.clientY = event.touches[0].clientY;
    onDocumentMouseDown( event );
}   
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;
    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );   
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );
    TWEEN.removeAll();
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {  
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
        document.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );            
        //controls.enabled = false;
        if (SELECTED) {     
            if (SELECTED == intersects[ 0 ].object) {
                if (opened == true) {
                    //same selected;
                    var angleSelectedInit = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x };
                    var angleSelectedEnd = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x - Math.PI/2 };                      
                    new TWEEN.Tween( angleSelectedInit ).to( angleSelectedEnd , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                    SELECTED.rotation.x = angleSelectedInit.x ;
                    opened = false;
                    }).onComplete(function(){
                        addListeners();
                        SELECTED = 0; // so the new selected condition wont rotate the closed selected face
                    }).start();     
                }   
                if (opened == false) {
                    //same selected;
                    var angleSelectedInit = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x };
                    var angleSelectedEnd = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x + Math.PI/2 };                      
                    new TWEEN.Tween( angleSelectedInit ).to( angleSelectedEnd , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                        //alert(SELECTED.rotation.x);
                    SELECTED.rotation.x = angleSelectedInit.x ;
                    opened = true;
                    }).onComplete(function(){
                        addListeners();
                    }).start();     
                }                   
            } else {
                if (SELECTED !== 0) {
                    var angleSelectedInit = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x };
                    var angleSelectedEnd = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x - Math.PI/2 };                      
                    new TWEEN.Tween( angleSelectedInit ).to( angleSelectedEnd , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                        //alert(SELECTED.rotation.x);
                    SELECTED.rotation.x = angleSelectedInit.x ;
                    }).onComplete(function(){
                    }).start(); 
                }
                //new selected; 
                //INTERSECTED VAR IS USED ON MOUSEMOVE EVENT = intersects[ 0 ].object;              
                var angleSelectedInitNew = { x: intersects[ 0 ].object.rotation.x };
                var angleSelectedEndNew = { x: intersects[ 0 ].object.rotation.x + Math.PI/2 };         
                new TWEEN.Tween( angleSelectedInitNew ).to( angleSelectedEndNew , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                    //alert(SELECTED.rotation.x);
                intersects[ 0 ].object.rotation.x = angleSelectedInitNew.x ;
                }).onComplete(function(){
                    SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                    addListeners();
                }).start();             
            }
        } else {            
            //first time selected;
            SELECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            var angleSelectedInit = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x };
            var angleSelectedEnd = { x: SELECTED.rotation.x + Math.PI/2 };          

            new TWEEN.Tween( angleSelectedInit ).to( angleSelectedEnd , 500).easing(TWEEN.Easing.Cubic.InOut).onUpdate(function(){
                //alert(SELECTED.rotation.x);
            SELECTED.rotation.x = angleSelectedInit.x ;
            opened = true;
            }).onComplete(function(){
                addListeners();
            }).start();     
        }       
    }   
}
function onDocumentMouseUp( event) {    
}
function addListeners() {
    document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false );
    document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );   
}
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    stats.update();
    TWEEN.update();
    controls.update();
}
function render() {
    //cubeMenu.pivot.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );               
}
```

I keep the scenario on a separated file:

scenario.js

```
function createScenario(scene) {

    container = document.createElement( 'div' );
    document.body.appendChild( container );

    scene.add( new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x505050 ) );

    var light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff, 1.5 );
    light.position.set( 0, 500, 2000 );
    light.castShadow = true;

    light.shadowCameraNear = 200;
    light.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
    light.shadowCameraFov = 50;

    light.shadowBias = -0.00022;

    light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
    light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

    scene.add( light );             

}
```

Bottom line, don't increment a value inside a tween.

I hope this code help someone in this community. Since most answers to build this code came from here.

Improvements are most welcome!

Thx.

Comment: fyi controls and stats must be called from the library